# Why are there no other constructors except for the default one in .edmx?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework in my C# projects for a database connection.

Let's say I have a table on my database which has 3 columns:
table: Car
columns: id, color, type, numberOfDoors

Here is how I create a new record for this table:

```
Car c = new Car();//default constructor
c.color = "blue";
c.type = "Opel";
c.numberOfDoors = 2;
myDatabase.tblCar.AddObject(c);
myDatabase.SaveChanges();
```

I'm doing this in a lot of places in my project, so the first 4 lines are repeated a lot. So I was thinking, why doesn't Entity Framework have a constructors with parameters? I thought that maybe the columns which can be null in db can be the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is trying to be as general as possible. Plus some models might have 10+ properties off of them. That would be quite messy if you only needed to assign a small subset of them. Another reason is that it would be messy to construct the models inside of Entity Framework.

The classes are generated with the `partial` keyword and you should be able to add it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

EF generates static constructor CreateX methods for each Entity (class) it generates. For example, on one of my User classes I can do the following:

```
User user = User.CreateUser(userID, password, email, userTypeId);
```

This does most of what you would want in terms of quickly setting up a new instance of an entity class. Of course this does NOT add the new instance to the collection or save changes; you might want to create 50,000 instances and saving every time would be wasteful.

Comment: But why does it need userID? My user's id is int and autoincremented.